# StringSplit with SubscriptBox

Tags: string-manipulation

My code has a problem

```
Row[Dynamic@Style[#, If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Black], 24] & /@ 
    StringSplit[#] &@"If I close a slit, by example \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\)", 
 Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

How can I find a solution?

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Row[Dynamic@ Style[#, If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Black], 24] & /@ 
  Append[StringSplit["If I close a slit, by example"], Subscript[r, 2]], Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. My problem was r2

Comment: If my text was:  If I close a slit, by example r2 and close r1. I need use `Row` or other command?.

Comment: @Andres, you can do `Row[Dynamic@
    Style[#, If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Black], 24] & /@ 
  Join[StringSplit[
    "If I close a slit, by example"], {Subscript[r, 2]}, 
   StringSplit["and close"], {Subscript[r, 1]}, {"."}], Spacer[5]]`.